# Pandas groupby: How to sort weekdays in the correct order when creating groupby with two columns?

Tags: pandas, seaborn, heatmap, pandas-groupby

The following dataframe contains values (kWh) for every hour of the year.

```
cons2016.head()

    Date        Hour    kWh     Month   Weekday
0   2016-01-01  00:00   71.48   January Friday
1   2016-01-01  01:00   65.32   January Friday
2   2016-01-01  02:00   65.38   January Friday
3   2016-01-01  03:00   62.44   January Friday
4   2016-01-01  04:00   57.56   January Friday
```

I want to create a Seaborn heatmap from this dataframe (weekdays in the **correct** order on vertical axis and hours on horizontal axis). So I groupby:

```
weekdayhour = cons2016.groupby(["Weekday", "Hour"]).mean()
weekdayhour = weekdayhour.reset_index()
weekdayhour.head()

    Weekday Hour    kWh
0   Friday  00:00   61.188113
1   Friday  01:00   57.231698
2   Friday  02:00   55.818679
3   Friday  03:00   55.074151
4   Friday  04:00   55.049811
```

But now the weekdays are in **alphabetical** order (also in the heatmap):

```
heat_weekdayhour = weekdayhour.pivot(index="Weekday", columns="Hour", values="kWh")
sns.heatmap(heat_weekdayhour)
```

[image: weekday order wrong in heatmap]

How can I get the weekdays in normal order, from Monday to Sunday? I tried adding .reindex like this:

```
weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
weekdayhour = cons2016.groupby(["Weekday", "Hour"]).mean().reindex(labels=weekdays)
```

But that gives me `TypeError: Expected tuple, got str`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Categorical`

```
weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
weekdayhour.Weekday = pd.Categorical(weekdayhour.Weekday,categories=weekdays)
weekdayhour = weekdayhour.sort_values('Weekday')
  Weekday   Hour    kWh
0  Friday  00:00  71.48
1  Friday  01:00  65.32
2  Friday  02:00  65.38
3  Friday  03:00  62.44
4  Friday  04:00  57.56
```

More Info:

```
weekdayhour.Weekday
0    Friday
1    Friday
2    Friday
3    Friday
4    Friday
Name: Weekday, dtype: category
Categories (7, object): [Monday < Tuesday < Wednesday < Thursday < Friday < Saturday < Sunday]
```

Comment: Thank you. So groupby wasn't needed for this at all!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

#You first create your list in the order you want it
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

#Using Categorical() function to set the order according to how it is arranged above
df["DOTW_Appointment"] = pd.Categorical(df.DOTW_Appointment, categories=days, ordered=True)
```